# Rails: PUMA cluster mode vs threaded only?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, heroku, digital-ocean, puma

In my rails app, hosted on the Digitalocean app platform, we're seeing high ram usage and can accommodate only 2 puma workers in a pro instance (1 vCPU, 2 GB Ram). Should I prefer more small instances without any workers as that would be more cost-effective?
i.e. if it was heroku, then should I use 2x dyno with more puma workers or multiple 1x dynos?

Is there any inherent advantage to using puma in cluster mode vs threaded only with more instances?

Comment: This is probably opinion-based. But if the cost for 2 small instances is the same as for 1 bigger instance and when both options could host the same number of threads/workers serving traffic then I would always prefer 2 smaller instances because then the app wouldn't be down if one instance fails. Additionally, rolling-restarts would be possible to deploy with zero downtime if supported by the platform. But in general, threaded vs clustered probably depends on your app's specific memory footprint.

Comment: @spickermann In general, my other apps uses around 385 MB, So I used to have a 2x Heroku dyno, about 3 workers and 5 threads. And was using jemalloc buildpack. But in this app of mine, which is on the Digitalocean app platform, I can't specify jemalloc build pack. So, it's using more ram even after the default MALLOC_ARENA_MAX is 2 on digitalocean. So, pricing wise it makes sense to use multiple instances, than a large instance. I wanted to know if there is any difference in the way puma handles slow clients etc when in cluster mode. If not, then I'll use puma in threaded only mode.